# RecyclerView with nested lists data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a Recyclerview to show a data that can be visualized like this:

```
Order
     FirstTypeOrders
       FirstTypeOrder[0]
           --title
           Item[0]
               --title
           Item[1]
               --title
           Item[2]
               --title
       FirstTypeOrder[1]
           --title
           Item[0]
               --title
           Item[1]
               --title
           Item[2]
               --title
     SecondTypeOrders
       SecondTypeOrder[0]
          --title
       SecondTypeOrder[1]
          --title
```

I have ran into a problem in getItemViewType() where i can't figure out the logic for seperating the view types. I have three viewtypes: one for displaying title of all FirstTypeOrders, one for displaying items in FirstTypeOrders, one for displaying title of all SecondTypeOrders.

Comment: Please post some code so we can at least see what data structures you are starting with.  You saw my answer to a similar question.  It's just a matter of taking your data, which can be viewed as a tree structure, and flattening it into a one-dimensional list.  This isn't very difficult.  Post the code you have already and we'll get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: actually,i've not started coding. i am deciding on various methods i should or should not use as of now. i am not expecting a code as an answer. just  a clear insight into how to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one idea: Actually create a heterogeneous list to represent the flattened list model

Let's say you have classes for each object you listed: `FirstTypeOrder`, `Item` and `SecondTypeOrder`.

You simply traverse your data and put each object in the list.

```
      private List<Object> mFlattenedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

...

```
      private void flatten(List<FirstTypeOrder> orders1, List<SecondTypeOrder> orders2) {

          for (FirstTypeOrder order1 : orders1) {
              mFlattenedList.add(order1);  // to get the title
              for (Item item : order1.getItems()) {
                  mFlattenedList.add(item);
              }
          }
          for (SecondTypeOrder order2 : orders2) {
              mFlattenedList.add(order2);  // to get the title
          }

      }
```

Now look what you have:

- For `getItemCount()` return the list size.
- For `bindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)`, you have an object at `position` from which to bind data.
- For `getItemViewType(int position)`, use `instanceof` object at `position` to determine which view type to return.

Simple.

Comment: yeah, i also thought of this method. just that i was a bit skeptical about the use of <Object> .

Comment: I understand, it feels like you're circumventing the whole type-safety mechanism.  I think it's valid to have a heterogeneous list in a situation like this.  You can always have your classes implement an empty marker interface and use that for the list item type, if it makes you feel better. :)