# how to display nested array in recycler view in different different row

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have data in given form and i want to display it in recyclerview as u can se every ledger have different number of item. i want to display these item with ledger, in this form i am mentioning at below please if possible give me code i am new in android.

```
 {"posts": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "ledger": "ledger1",
       "credit" : "343"
       "item": [
         {"id":10,
          "rate": 5,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 250
         },
         {"id":12,
          "rate": 50,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 2500
         }
       ] 
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "ledger": "ledger2",
       "credit" : "343"
       "item": [
         {"id":10,
          "rate": 5,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 250
         },
         {"id":42,
          "rate": 50,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 2500
         },
         {"id":17,
          "rate": 50,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 2500
         },
         {"id":12,
          "rate": 50,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 2500
         }
       ] 
     },
     {
       "id": 3,
       "ledger": "ledger",
       "credit" : "1000",
       "item": []
    ]}

**id   ledger     credit**
--------------------------
1      ledger1    343
*id   iRate   qty   total*
10    5       50   250
12    50      50   2500
_________________________
2     ledger2    343
*id   iRate   qty   total*
10    5       50   250
42    50      50   2500
12    50      50   2500
17    50      50   2500
__________________________
3     ledger3    1000
```

i want to make recycler view which will display data is this formate for ledger and their corresponding item
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using two RecyclerView;

- First `RecyclerView` with `post` ViewHolder.
- Second `RecyclerView` with `post.item` ViewHolder.

The other way, using [epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific data structure to retain this in one data. You can implement this with just 1 recyclerView instead of 2 recyclerView. Anyways 2 recyclerView is never the suggested approach.

JSON had some formatting issues. This is the updated JSON -

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "ledger": "ledger1",
      "credit": "343",
      "item": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "rate": 5,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 250
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "rate": 50,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 2500
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "ledger": "ledger2",
      "credit": "343",
      "item": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "rate": 5,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 250
        },
        {
          "id": 42,
          "rate": 50,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 2500
        },
        {
          "id": 17,
          "rate": 50,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 2500
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "rate": 50,
          "qty": 50,
          "total": 2500
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "ledger": "ledger",
      "credit": "1000",
      "item": [
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Models or object classes can be as follows:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Item.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Item {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("rate")
@Expose
private Integer rate;
@SerializedName("qty")
@Expose
private Integer qty;
@SerializedName("total")
@Expose
private Integer total;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Integer getRate() {
return rate;
}

public void setRate(Integer rate) {
this.rate = rate;
}

public Integer getQty() {
return qty;
}

public void setQty(Integer qty) {
this.qty = qty;
}

public Integer getTotal() {
return total;
}

public void setTotal(Integer total) {
this.total = total;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Post.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Post {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("ledger")
@Expose
private String ledger;
@SerializedName("credit")
@Expose
private String credit;
@SerializedName("item")
@Expose
private List<Item> item = null;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getLedger() {
return ledger;
}

public void setLedger(String ledger) {
this.ledger = ledger;
}

public String getCredit() {
return credit;
}

public void setCredit(String credit) {
this.credit = credit;
}

public List<Item> getItem() {
return item;
}

public void setItem(List<Item> item) {
this.item = item;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.PostsResponse.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class PostsResponse {

@SerializedName("posts")
@Expose
private List<Post> posts = null;

public List<Post> getPosts() {
return posts;
}

public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
this.posts = posts;
}

}
```

Data Structure can be as follows:

`List<LedgerItem>` - This goes as input to the RecyclerView as the List

You need to `map` the `Post` to the `LedgerItem` object.

1. Every `Post` Object will have the `ledgerViewType` as the `LEDGER_MAIN`
2. Every time you start looping over the items, you will add a `LedgerItem` which will have the header row and will have the `ledgerViewType` as the `LEDGER_HEADER`. You can skip this by creating a better layout which labels every item in a proper way. Check this screenshot. [image]
3. Every `Item` Object will have the `ledgerViewType` as the `TRANSACTION_ITEM`.

You can loop over the items and keep adding all items. You will have a flattened list.

You can refer this answer for some more explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40570333/4491971

```
    public class LedgerItem {
        private String uniqueId;
        private Post post;
        private Item item;
        private int ledgerViewType;
    }
```

```
    public static enum LedgerViewType {
        LEDGER_MAIN(100),
        TRANSACTION_ITEM(200),
        LEDGER_HEADER(300);
    }
```

Every `PostViewHolder` can have list of items. So you can use the `onBindViewHolder` to load the Items. Based on the ViewType, you can have ViewHolders that handle the data display accordingly. For example, `PostViewHolder` will read data from `ledgerItem.post` and so on.